# How to AES-GCM for iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, encryption, aes-gcm

i want to create AES encrypt and decrypt GCM mode with authentication tag.
This is my source code of iOS version:

```
CCCryptorStatus ccStatus = kCCSuccess;
NSData *iv = [hexIV dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData *symmetricKey = [hexIV dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSMutableData  *dataOut = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:self.length];
NSMutableData  *tag = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:kCCBlockSizeAES128];
size_t          tagLength = kCCBlockSizeAES128;

ccStatus = CCCryptorGCM(kCCEncrypt,
                        kCCAlgorithmAES,
                        symmetricKey.bytes,
                        kCCKeySizeAES256,
                        iv.bytes,
                        iv.length,
                        aad.bytes,
                        aad.length,
                        self.bytes,
                        self.length,
                        dataOut.mutableBytes,
                        tag.bytes,
                        &tagLength);

if (ccStatus == kCCSuccess) {
    return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:dataOut,@"cyphertext",tag,@"tag",iv,@"iv",nil];
} else {
    return nil;
}
```

I want to change this code to Android version, below Android's source code:

```
byte[] aKey = hexStringToByteArray(hexKey);
byte[] aIV = hexStringToByteArray(hexIV);
Key key = new SecretKeySpec(aKey, "AES");
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, new GCMParameterSpec(16 * Byte.SIZE, aIV));
cipher.updateAAD(aad);
byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(aKey);
```

How to add authentication tag into my source code?

Answer (score 0):

When i encrypt AES GCM in iOS

```
let iv = AES.GCM.Nonce()
let sealedBox = try! AES.GCM.seal(rawJsonData, 
                                  using: yourKey, 
                                  nonce: yourIv)
let cipher = sealedBox.ciphertext + sealedBox.tag
```

Remember, in android you have: IV + Cipher + Tag

you can easily reproduce this in iOS to decrypt, following the same structure,

```
let incomingCipher = (payload?.fromBase64())!
let IV = initialVector?.fromBase64()
let combine = IV! + incomingCipher
let myNewSealedBox = try AES.GCM.SealedBox(combined: combine)
```

Where incomingCipher (Android) Contains cipher + Tag